# How to solve $\int_0^1\:\frac{\ln(x)\:\Big[1+x^{-\frac{1}{3}}\Big]}{(1-x)\sqrt[3]{x}}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can we solve this integral?
$\int_0^1\:\frac{\ln(x)\:\Big[1+x^{-\frac{1}{3}}\Big]}{(1-x)\sqrt[3]{x}}\:dx$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: $x^{-1/3}$ complicates the floor function a bit..

Comment: @Nikunj i think this is an ordinary bracket, but who knows

Comment: @tired I think we use digamma function but ı do not apply

Comment: Did you try any simplifications or substitutions

Comment: Is it the floor function or not OP clarify please

Comment: i actually know how to solve this, but i'm not in the mood to answer a question which is posed in low quality way

Comment: @tired the best I get is $9\int _0^{1} \frac{\log x (1+x)dx}{1-x^3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subbing $x=u^3$ is very natural here and leads to a simple sum...

$$I = \int_0^1 dx \frac{\left (1+x^{-1/3} \right ) \log{x}}{x^{1/3} (1-x)} = 9 \int_0^1 du \, \frac{(1+u) \log{u}}{1-u^3}$$

Expand the denominator...

$$\begin{align}I &= 9 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 du \, (1+u) u^{3 k} \log{u}\\ &= -9 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac1{(3 k+1)^2} + \frac1{(3 k+2)^2} \right ) \\ &= -9 \frac{\pi^2}{6} + 9 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac1{(3 k+3)^2}\\ &= - \frac{9\pi^2}{6} + \frac{\pi^2}{6}\\ &= -\frac{4 \pi^2}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: This is much easier than what I did. Great answer

Comment: @YuriyS: Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\int_0^1 x^a dx = \frac{1}{a+1}$$

$$\int_0^1 x^a \log x ~dx = -\frac{1}{(a+1)^2}$$

$$\int_0^1 x^b x^q \log x ~dx = -\frac{1}{(b+q+1)^2}$$

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{b=0}^{\infty} x^b x^q \log x ~dx = -\sum_{b=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(b+q+1)^2}$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^q \log x}{1-x} ~dx = -\sum_{b=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(b+q+1)^2}=-\zeta(2,q+1)=-\psi^{(1)}(q+1) $$

With the last two expressions being Hurwitz zeta and polygamma functions respectively.

So, in your case:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(x^{-1/3}+x^{-2/3}) \log x}{1-x} ~dx =-\zeta \left(2,\frac{2}{3} \right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{1}{3} \right) =-\psi^{(1)} \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)-\psi^{(1)} \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)$$

Using the reference provided by @tired

$$\psi^{(1)} \left(z \right)+\psi^{(1)} \left(1-z \right)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2 (\pi z)}$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(x^{-1/3}+x^{-2/3}) \log x}{1-x} ~dx =-\frac{4\pi^2}{3}$$

Comment: $\psi^{(1)}(1/3)+\psi^{(1)}(2/3)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi/3)}=\frac{4}{3}\pi^2$ by reflection

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function
just put $z=1/3$ in the reflection formula found in the link above

Comment: Can I update the answer (mentioning you)?

Comment: Sure, go ahead!